# How will be the energy consumption curve of a Li-Ion / Li-Polymer charger?

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, battery-charging, dc, power-electronics

All the battery chargers I've seen simply say 10 or 20 W or etc. But what confuses me is the constant current - constant voltage charging algorithm.
For example I've started recharging at 3 V and it's in constant current charging (500 mA) until it reaches 4.15 V, then it reaches constant voltage charging mode. Will it consume a fixed amount of power until the termination of charging?

Comment: Each value for each physical quantity stated is peak. Constant power charging is a thing but uncommon and mainly a result of thermal foldback and not a desirable characteristic.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** No

**Longer Answer:**

What's written as power consumption (or delivery) of a device is always the maximum power consumption. In some cases it might be, what the devices really use but in most cases it's just some made up worst case number without a lot of relevance for low power devices.

There are basically three ways to control the output of a power delivery device.

- Constant Voltage (CV)
- Constant Current (CC)
- Constant Power (CP)

The most common one is "CV"

As you mentioned, in battery charging you're normally switching between CC nd CV. CP is somewhat hard to implement and not often used.

The power consumption of your device will change with the power it delivers to the batteries. Since you don't have 100% efficiency it will always consume more power than will be delivered to the load but it won't be constant.

Comment: Also, it will be the average of all that power so, if initially it's high and then it decays then the bill will show the average of all of it.

Comment: The bill shows the energy that was consumed, not the power. For some definition of the word "average" you could for sure call it an average.

Comment: What I meant was: if the device draws 60 W for 10 min and then 50 min nothing then the average of it will be 10 W/hr. You could call it energy, or (active) power (if on a residential location), or simply "what the bill shows" (this is why I used the words "bill" and "average"). To be more clear: I am not disagreeing with your answer, I was just adding the fact that there is an average involved, if we're talking about energy consumption (as per the OP).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen W/h is not a unit that is used normally... It's Wh. And no, we **could** not call it energy. It **is** energy. And what your bill sows **is** energy. You can say: in average we used x W. That's an average. But what's on your bill is energy consumption. Please stop confusing energy and power. There are too many people out there doing that already.